# CV split for time series data

Tags: python, scikit-learn, time-series, cross-validation

I'm currently working in ts data and what I'm trying to do is to generate cross-validation sets for model evaluation. This is how I'm doing it:

```
# Splitting train & validation
df['date_posted'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_posted'])
df_train = df[(df['date_posted'].dt.year > 2009) & (df['date_posted'].dt.year < 2014)].copy()
df_test = df[df['date_posted'].dt.year >= 2014].copy()

from sklearn.model_selection import GroupShuffleSplit

groups = df_train.groupby(df_train['date_posted'].dt.year).groups

X = df_train.drop(['short_description', 'is_exciting'], axis=1).copy()
y = df_train['is_exciting']

cv = GroupShuffleSplit().split(X, y, groups)

# Baseline model 

from sklearn.model_selection import KFold

clf_lgbm = lgbm.LGBMClassifier(is_unbalance=True, random_state=0, n_jobs=-1)
# cv = KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=0)

results = cross_val_score(clf_lgbm, X, y, cv=cv)

print("Accuracy: %.3f%% (%.3f%%)" % (results.mean()*100.0, results.std()*100.0))
```

And this is the error traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-7091271a325a> in <module>()
      6 # cv = KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=0)
      7 
----> 8 results = cross_val_score(clf_lgbm, X, y, cv=cv)
      9 
     10 print("Accuracy: %.3f%% (%.3f%%)" % (results.mean()*100.0, results.std()*100.0))

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py in cross_val_score(estimator, X, y, groups, scoring, cv, n_jobs, verbose, fit_params, pre_dispatch)
    340                                 n_jobs=n_jobs, verbose=verbose,
    341                                 fit_params=fit_params,
--> 342                                 pre_dispatch=pre_dispatch)
    343     return cv_results['test_score']
    344 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py in cross_validate(estimator, X, y, groups, scoring, cv, n_jobs, verbose, fit_params, pre_dispatch, return_train_score)
    192     X, y, groups = indexable(X, y, groups)
    193 
--> 194     cv = check_cv(cv, y, classifier=is_classifier(estimator))
    195     scorers, _ = _check_multimetric_scoring(estimator, scoring=scoring)
    196 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_split.py in check_cv(cv, y, classifier)
   1913                              "object (from sklearn.model_selection) "
   1914                              "or an iterable. Got %s." % cv)
-> 1915         return _CVIterableWrapper(cv)
   1916 
   1917     return cv  # New style cv objects are passed without any modification

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_split.py in __init__(self, cv)
   1815     """Wrapper class for old style cv objects and iterables."""
   1816     def __init__(self, cv):
-> 1817         self.cv = list(cv)
   1818 
   1819     def get_n_splits(self, X=None, y=None, groups=None):

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_split.py in split(self, X, y, groups)
   1201         to an integer.
   1202         """
-> 1203         X, y, groups = indexable(X, y, groups)
   1204         for train, test in self._iter_indices(X, y, groups):
   1205             yield train, test

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in indexable(*iterables)
    227         else:
    228             result.append(np.array(X))
--> 229     check_consistent_length(*result)
    230     return result
    231 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_consistent_length(*arrays)
    202     if len(uniques) > 1:
    203         raise ValueError("Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of"
--> 204                          " samples: %r" % [int(l) for l in lengths])
    205 
    206 

ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [439599, 439599, 4]
```

X shape is (439599, 51) and y shape is (439599,).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the requirement of `groups` param at [the documentation of GroupShuffleSplit](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GroupShuffleSplit.html#sklearn.model_selection.GroupShuffleSplit.split):

> ```
> groups : array-like, with shape (n_samples,), optional
>
>     Group labels for the samples used while splitting 
>     the dataset into train/test set.
> ```

The length of groups should be equal to the number of samples, with each value indicating the group label its a part of.

The output of this line:

```
groups = df_train.groupby(df_train['date_posted'].dt.year).groups
```

is a dict where key is the group label and value is the indices of rows belonging to that column. But this is not what scikit-learn expects.

For example, for this data:

```
Index   A  B  #Columns
  0     0  2  
  1     3  1  
  2     0  0  
  3     0  0 
  4     0  2
```

If you want the first three rows to belong to group1 and last two columns to belong to group2, then you need to pass the `groups` as:

```
 groups=['group1','group1','group1','group2','group2']
```

or

```
groups=[0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
```

Observe that here, total values are 5, corresponding to the rows in my data, and each value represent the group the row at that index belongs to.

So in your case, you can convert the returned dict to a list by using the below code:

```
import numpy as np

groups_proper = np.zeros(len(df_train))          
for val in groups.iteritems():
    for index in val[1].tolist():
        groups_proper[index]=val[0]
```

And then pass it:

```
cv = GroupShuffleSplit().split(X, y, groups=groups_proper)
```